# get count(*) from 3rd table using 2nd table foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get count(*) from 3rd table `tbl_RUR_Enclosures` using 2nd table foreign key`tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands`.

**Sorry It was mistake, I have given wrong SQL query. Updated one is here***

### Updated

```
select [loan number] as LoanNum, [Finding ID] as FindingID, 
       [Finding Topic], [Finding Narrative], [Reps Breached],  T.*,
     (select COUNT(*) from dbo.tbl_RUR_Enclosures where 
        tbl_RUR_Enclosures.[Finding ID]=tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands.
        [Finding ID]) 
     from dbo.tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands as RR join  
     [tbl_DefectFindingEnclosuresMateriality] as T on 
     T.[AP_ID] = RR.[AP_ID] where [loan number] in 
     (select [Loan Number] from tbl_RUR_Comprehensive 
       where Shelf = 'CWABS' and Series='2004-K' and Batch=1 
       and [Loan Number]='41090261' ) order by [Loan Number]
```

It is throwing error `Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands.Finding ID" could not be bound.`

Help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting queries does wonder to understanding such problems:

```
select [loan num] ,[Finding ID] as FindingID,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from dbo.tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands
        where [Finding ID]=tbl_RUR_Comprehensive.[Finding ID]
       )
from dbo.tbl_RUR_Enclosures
where [loan num] in (select [Loan Number]
                     from tbl_RUR_Comprehensive 
                     where Shelf = 'CWABS' and Series='2004-K' and Batch=1)
order by [loan num]
```

You have a correlated query in the `select` statement.  The correlation, though, is to a subquery in the `where` clause.  That is not allowed.  Even if it were, the subquery is not returning the column you are asking for.

I think this is a simple mistake, because the `select` suggests that the column is in the table in the `from` clause.  If so, you can fix this as:

```
select [loan num] ,[Finding ID] as FindingID,
       (select COUNT(*)
        from dbo.tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands
        where tbl_RUR_RepurchaseDemands.[Finding ID] = tbl_RUR_Enclosures.[Finding ID]
       )
from dbo.tbl_RUR_Enclosures
where [loan num] in (select [Loan Number]
                     from tbl_RUR_Comprehensive 
                     where Shelf = 'CWABS' and Series='2004-K' and Batch=1)
order by [loan num];
```

Comment: I have updated with new query. Sorry, I was typed wrong query. Please ignore previous one.